# Flex: Bottom-left align components?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

As the title suggests, is there any way to bottom-left align components?

An `<HBox .../>` nested in a `<Canvas .../>` doesn't work because the elements in the `HBox` are top-aligned instead of bottom aligned.

For example, I'd like my components to be aligned like this:

```
+-------------+ <-- container
| components  |
|  |    V     |
|  V  +--+    |
| +-+ |  |    |
| +-+ +--+    |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the verticalAlign and horizontalAlign styles on the hbox ie:

```
<mx:Canvas>
<mx:HBox verticalAlign="bottom" horizontalAlign="left" left="0" bottom="0"> </mx:HBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I wish I knew why I missed the "verticalAlign" property.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the HBox and/or Box to change the positioning.  I suspect you'll probably have to override the updateDisplayList method to change the way components are positioned.  Probably instead of setting the y value as "0" you'll want to set it to unscaledHeight-component.width.

Comment: If the veritalAlign style works w/ HBoxes, you're right; this is serious overkill.